# Problem with Views 7.x-3.0 - Column not found

Tags: 7, views

I just updated the views from 7.x-3.0-rc1
 to version 7.x-3.0 and now I'm getting the following error when executing my view:

`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'field_data_field_category.nid' in 'on clause'`

The generated query looks like this:

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title, 
       node.nid AS nid, 
       node_field_data_field_category.title AS node_field_data_field_category_title,
      'node' AS field_data_field_color_node_entity_type, 
      'node' AS field_data_field_image_node_entity_type, 
      'node' AS field_data_field_sale_node_entity_type
FROM {node} node
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_category} field_data_field_category ON node.nid = 
                                      field_data_field_category.entity_id AND 
                                      (field_data_field_category.entity_type = 'node' AND 
                                      field_data_field_category.deleted = '0')
LEFT JOIN {node} node_field_data_field_category ON field_data_field_category.nid = 
                 node_field_data_field_category.nid
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_gender} field_data_field_gender ON node.nid = 
                                    field_data_field_gender.entity_id AND
                                    (field_data_field_gender.entity_type = 'node' AND
                                    field_data_field_gender.deleted = '0')
WHERE (((node.type IN  ('product')) AND (node.status = '1') AND
        (field_data_field_gender.field_gender_value IN  ('0', '1'))));
```

I see that the `field_data_field_category.nid` should be `field_data_field_category.field_category_nid`, but how do I solve this without using something like `hook_query_alter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the `references` module, I found this [patch](https://drupal.org/files/issues/column_not_found_1054_unkonw_column-1275096-8.patch) wich solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the data for the field is wrong or incomplete. You can fix this with hook_views_data_alter. Not knowing anything about the field, it's hard to say what to do exactly. At worse, you need to create a custom handler.